# Where is the backup folder of TextSecure and Signal?

Tags: backup, sms, textsecure, signal-private-messenger

In TextSecure, you can choose to backup your SMS to the SDCard.

It says "Success" but there is no evidence where it does store it on the SDCard.

I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Chahk said, the folder is `/sdcard/TextSecureExport`. I've had trouble accessing it (even after moving it) over the camera-centric USB interfaces.

I ended up compressing the file to a Zip archive using [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) and then using Google Drive to browse and upload the file. This also makes it easy to pull back down to a different device or after wiping memory.

Comment: I'd recommend encrypting it first before copying it to Google Drive (with something like [APG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thialfihar.android.apg&hl=en)) unless you're happy with Google seeing all of your "secure" text messages.

Comment: The backup is already encrypted by TextSecure, unless you back up with the option to not do that.

Answer (score 4):

The folder is located just in the base dir of your SDcard:

```
/sdcard/TextSecureExport
```

Since Textsecure is now called Signal, there is no extra folder. It is located directly in your SDcard home folder:

```
/sdcard/SignalPlaintextBackup.xml
```

Note: sometimes the phone doesen't show the folder on your computer, then you could use a filemanager on your phone (like [Ghost Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander)) to move the backupped files into another folder that is visible on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

My Android Signal app version 4.10.12 (date 2017/10/01) saves media of conversations in Device storage > Pictures.